# System.ExecutionEngineException, Net2.0, x86, change code on debugging

Tags: c#

I have a WindowsForms application x86 and a library also with x86 compile configuration. Both Net2.0

The two classes in the library look like this.

```
public class Class1
{
    private List<Class2> _test;

    public Class1()
    {
        _test = new List<Class2>();
    }

    public bool Test() //breakpoint
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(" "); 
        //change content from Trace.WriteLine
        //exception with the loop in the catch block
        //without for loop no exception

        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            foreach (Class2 item in _test)
            {

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class Class2
{

}
```

The class class1 is instantiated in the windows forms application and the method Test is called.
A breakpoint is set at the function entry.
If I now change the code in the function (e.g. cahnge content from Trace.WriteLine), it comes to a System.ExecutionEngineException in the windows forms application.

If I comment out on the FOR loop in the CATCH block of Class1 and execute the application again and change again the code in the Test function, this exception does not occur.

The exception occurs in the windows forms application on the commented line.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1()); //The excption is occured on this line
    }
}
```

Why does this exception occur? How can I prevent this?

Greetings Henrik

Comment: Please show the code that constructs a Class1 object and calls Class1.Test

Comment: It is a debugger bug, the VS version matters a lot.  A possible workaround is Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  If you don't see that option then your VS version is very old, be sure to install all the service packs for it.

Comment: "Edit and Continue" is not supported in managed compatibility mode. This isn't what I wanted.
@ClaudiuGuiman: ``Class1 c = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
c.Test(); ``

Comment: @HansPassant, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" don't let me edit the code. "Edit and Continue" is not supported. (see my last comment). The major problem is: If I change some code on other places in bigger applications, the same exception is occured. And I cannot see where the exception is triggered.